# What is this shell doing?

Tags: c, shell

I was presented with this code as an example of how to make a 'mini shell' but I have no idea what it is doing-- I understand most things in the main function, but the functions above it initializing I'm really quite lost on.

Any basics on how a shell works and some of the lower level functions in C would be much appreciated.

```
log_t Log;

void printLog(log_t *l){
  log_entry_t *tmp = l->tail;
  while(tmp != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", tmp->value);
    tmp = tmp->prev;
  }
}

int countArg(char *line){
  unsigned int i, count = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++){
    if(line[i] == ' ')
      count++;
  }
  return count + 1;
}

char **makeargv(char *line){
  char *buff;
  char **retv;
  unsigned int i, count, arg_num = 0;

  buff = malloc((strlen(line) + 1) * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(buff, line);

  arg_num = countArg(buff);

  retv = malloc((arg_num + 1) * sizeof(char*));

  retv[arg_num] = NULL;
  retv[0] = buff;

  for(i = 0, count = 1; buff[i]!='\0'; i++){
    if(buff[i] == ' '){
      buff[i]='\0';
      retv[count] = buff + i + 1; 
      count++;
    }
  }
  return retv;
}


int main()
{
  log_init(&Log);
  char * line;

  while(1){
    size_t size;
    char * cwd = NULL;
    char * query = NULL;
    char * match = NULL;

    int f_exit = 0,
    f_nbi=0,
    f_match=0,
    f_sys = 0,
    f_path=0;

    // print out the requested prompt
    cwd = getcwd(NULL,0); 
    printf("$(pid=%d)%s$ ", getpid(), cwd );
    free(cwd);

    line = NULL;
    fflush(stdout);
    getline(&line, &size, stdin);
    line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';

    while(1){
      if(strcmp(line, "exit") == 0){
        if(f_match) printf("%s matches %s\n", query, line);
        f_exit = 1;
        printf("Command executed by pid=%d\n",getpid());
        log_destroy(&Log);
        break;
      }
      else if(strncmp(line, "cd ", 3) == 0){
        if(f_match) printf("%s matches %s\n", query, line);
        printf("Command executed by pid=%d\n",getpid());
        log_push(&Log, line);
        if(chdir(line + 3) != 0){
          printf("%s: No such file or directory\n",(line + 3));
        }
        break;
      }
      else if(strcmp(line, "!#") == 0){
        if(f_match) printf("%s matches %s\n", query, line);
        printf("Command executed by pid=%d\n",getpid());
        printLog(&Log);
        break;
      }
      else if(strstr(line,"!")==line){
        if(f_match) printf("%s matches %s\n", query, line);
        query = line+1;
        match = log_search(&Log, query);

        if(match==NULL){
          printf("Command executed by pid=%d\n",getpid());
          printf("No Match\n");        
          break;
        }
        else{
          f_match = 1;
          printf("Command executed by pid=%d\n",getpid());
          line = malloc((strlen(match)+1)*sizeof(char));
          strcpy(line, match);
          continue;
        }
      }
      else{
        f_nbi = 1;
        log_push(&Log,line);
        if(strstr(line,"/"))
          f_path = 1;       
        break;
      }
    }

    if(f_exit)
      break;

    if(f_nbi){
      pid_t pid = fork();
      if(pid == 0){ //child
        if(f_match){
          printf("%s matches %s\n", query, line);
          free(query-1);
        }

        printf("Command executed by pid=%d\n",getpid());
        char **argv = makeargv(line);
        f_sys = 0;

        if(f_path)
          f_sys = execv(argv[0],&argv[0]);
        else
          f_sys = execvp(argv[0],&argv[0]);

        if(f_sys == -1)
          printf("%s: not found\n",line);

        free(argv[0]);
        free(argv);
        log_destroy(&Log);
        exit(0);

    } 
    else { //parent
      waitpid(pid, NULL, WUNTRACED);
      if(f_match)
        free(query-1);
      }  
    }
    free(line);
    line = NULL;
  }
  if(line != NULL){
    free(line);
    line = NULL;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to indent code sanely. First prepare the code without any tabs; I recommend that you use 4 spaces of indent, but anything consistent (2, 3, 4, 8) is acceptable.  Paste it into the edit box, then select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it all.

Comment: I still don't really understand what this is doing, if anyone could explain it.

Comment: Three different reformattings of the code and I'm not sure I like the inconsistent spacing in the two later ones.  Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

The `printLog()` function is simply printing all the data from a linked list of records in a structure type given the name `log_t` by a `typedef`. It starts at the tail of the list and works backwards.  It is not clear whether the list is single-linked or double-linked, but the `prev` usually only appears in a double-linked list.

The `countArgs()` function is a crude way of determining how many arguments are present on a command line.  It is crude because it does not take into account quotes or multiple adjacent spaces.  However, those merely mean it overestimates the number of arguments, which is not serious.  It doesn't recognize tabs as separators, which is unusual for a shell.

The `makeargv()` function splits a command line into a series of space separated words and returns the list of words to the calling function.  It effectively parses the command line, making sure there's a null pointer at the end of the command line.  Again, it is simplistic, but sufficient.  It is also inconsistently named compared with the other two functions.

Comment: Ok, but why do we need these functions? What would happen if you tried to run the shell program above without them?